# MySQLSyntaxErrorException in Hibernate My SQL version

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat

i have the following hibernate configuration:

```
<bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
            <value>com.google.hacatone.entity.MainCategory</value>
            <value>com.google.hacatone.entity.GeorgianGrapes</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

when i try to select data from table i get the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'georgiangr0_' at line 1
```

please help me how to fix this problem, i try to use any mysql driver but problem not change

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "main_category", catalog = "hacatone_db")
public class MainCategory implements java.io.Serializable {
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "georgian_ grapes", catalog = "hacatone_db")
public class GeorgianGrapes implements java.io.Serializable {
}
```

this is my entity, how to force hibernate to generate right query?

Comment: Can you post the full exception that you get?

Comment: You are printing the sql statement causing the problem with hibernate.show_sql, so can you provide it?

Comment: Please add the SQL and schema, this will help us debug the issue for you.

Comment: this is generated query : select georgiangr0_.id as id1_, georgiangr0_.birthdate as birthdate1_, georgiangr0_.calories as calories1_, georgiangr0_.category as category1_, georgiangr0_.color as color1_, georgiangr0_.description as descript6_1_, georgiangr0_.name as name1_, georgiangr0_.origin as origin1_, georgiangr0_.raion as raion1_, georgiangr0_.region as region1_ from hacatone_db.georgian_ grapes georgiangr0_

Comment: Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'georgiangr0_' at line 1
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

Comment: I have two entity, first works  very well this is sql query:select this_.id as id0_0_, this_.category_img as category2_0_0_, this_.category_name as category3_0_0_ from hacatone_db.main_category this_

Comment: second entity sql query is this: select this_.id as id1_0_, this_.birthdate as birthdate1_0_, this_.calories as calories1_0_, this_.category as category1_0_, this_.color as color1_0_, this_.description as descript6_1_0_, this_.name as name1_0_, this_.origin as origin1_0_, this_.raion as raion1_0_, this_.region as region1_0_ from hacatone_db.georgian_ grapes this_

Comment: why is second query incorrect, also i try to run query in phpMyadmin and is error, firs query works in phpmyadmin also.

Comment: Maybe you have an extra space character: instead of `from hacatone_db.georgian_ grapes this_` try `from hacatone_db.georgian_grapes this_` in your second query...

Comment: I try to change my query: select this_.id as id1_0_, this_.birthdate as birthdate1_0_, this_.calories as calories1_0_, this_.category as category1_0_, this_.color as color1_0_, this_.description as descript6_1_0_, this_.img as img1_0_, this_.name as name1_0_, this_.origin as origin1_0_, this_.raion as raion1_0_, this_.region as region1_0_ from hacatone_db.georgian_ grapes this_

Comment: but this also not working

Comment: You're using MySQL server version 5.X right?